# Does creating an instance of a subclass automatically run the superclass's constructor?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have these classes:

```
public class Animal {

  static int counter = 0;

  public Animal() {
    counter += 1;
    System.out.println("Animals counter is currently " + counter);
}



public class Cat extends Animal {

  static int counter1 = 0;

  public Cat() {
    counter1 += 1;
    System.out.println("Cats counter is currently " + counter1);
}



public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat Cat1 = new Cat();
    Animal Animal1 = new Animal();
    Cat Cat2 = new Cat();
  }
}
```

When I run Main, I get the following output:

```
Animals counter is currently 1
Cats counter is currently 1
Animals counter is currently 2
Animals counter is currently 3
Cats counter is currently 2
```

So whenever I create an instance of Cat, it also increases the Animal counter. I'd like to clear up why this happens. Obviously, the constructor for Animal is running each time I create a Cat, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously, the constructor for Animal is running each time I create a Cat, but why?

Because `Cat` is sub class of `Animal` class, When you create an instance of sub class, by default the default constructor of the super class is called.

Internally this is something like this:

```
public Cat() {
  super(); // call to Animal class constructor.
  counter1 += 1;
  System.out.println("Cats counter is currently " + counter1);
}
```

The inheritance represents `is-a` relationship, `Cat` is an `Animal`.

---

Currently `static int counter = 0;` the `counter` variable is declared as static, which means that it will belong to the class not the instances of the class. So all the instance of the class will share the `counter` variable. That is why the `counter` is keeps on increasing as you create instance of sub class and super class.

When you make is `non-static`, it will be included into the state of the class as the instance member. Which mean, every time super class `Animal` constructor is called, its value is incremented to 1 (default is 0, you have also mentioned that), either directly or in-directly via sub-class constructor.

Comment: If that's the case, why is it that if I remove the static qualifier for the counter variable in animal, my output changes? Shouldn't it be updating the counter regardless? This is what I get if I remove static from counter in Animal:

Animals counter is currently 1
Cats counter is currently 1
Animals counter is currently 1
Animals counter is currently 1
Cats counter is currently 2

Comment: @SakeebHossain I have updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 3):

When inheriting from another class, super() has to be called first in the constructor. If not, the compiler will insert that call. This is why super constructor is also invoked when a Sub object is created.

This doesn't create two objects, only one Sub object. The reason to have super constructor called is that if super class could have private fields which need to be initialized by its constructor.

After compiler inserts the super constructor, the sub class constructor looks like the following:

```
public Cat() {
    super(); //implicit call
    counter1 += 1;
    System.out.println("Cats counter is currently " + counter1);
}
```

**Note:-** If you have parameterized constructor and you don't write super(), you will get an compilation error . You have to explicitly mention with parameters you are passing.

Edit:-

A brief overview about static in java from Java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) which says static data memebers are associated with the class, rather than with any
object

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.

Comment: If that's the case, why is it that if I remove the static qualifier for the counter variable in animal, my output changes? Shouldn't it be updating the counter regardless? This is what I get if I remove static from counter in Animal: Animals counter is currently 1 Cats counter is currently 1 Animals counter is currently 1 Animals counter is currently 1 Cats counter is currently 2 (sorry about the format)

Comment: @SakeebHossain Mark the answer as ACCEPTED if your problem is resolved.In this way it will help others looking for similar problem